# Unable to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on packard bell imedia S2185 with win 8 previously instlled

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, busybox

I was following the guide at:

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

I changed the BIOS to show the boot menu and selected the 14.04 installation USB drive.

Next, when prompted, I selected, "Try Ubuntu without installing"

This brings me to a screen displaying:

*BusyBox v1.21.1* etc. finishing in a mount failure

*failed: No such device*

*Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on //filesystem.squashfs*

Any ideas why Ubuntu will not run?

Comment: Thanks Karel, I totally missed that.  Unfortunately, the update seems to be the same content and steps, (I think he is trying to monetise his earlier guide!). I finally fluked it.  **I was using **universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3 to create the boot** usb stick.  The default persistant storage is 0MB.  I increased it to **1GB and the device booted.  **

Comment: Official Universal USB Installer tutorial at www.ubuntu.com -- [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: Much obliged, thanks Karel.  This is resolved as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I was using **universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3** to create the boot usb stick.

The default persistent storage on the app is **0MB**. I increased it to **1.1GB** and Ubuntu live booted off the USB device.

Comment: As Karel gave you the input you needed, it would have been polite to ask him if he'd want to answer the question before you did...  (you still can!  ;-) )